# I change part color of svg image and load it to flutter file but change is not reflected

Tags: flutter, svg

I change `svg` color from black to pink only check part as below by illustrator.

[image]

and upload it to flutter assets folder.

But it shows only black check box as before.

[image]

I did `flutter clean` but it also doens't work.

I need to change only part of svg file.

by Kotlin, I could change it by Android studio with `xml` file, but by flutter, How can I do this?

Now I use visual studio code.

`svg code`

```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 26.5.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FF2D78;}
</style>
<g>
    <path d="M394.7,512H117.3C52.6,511.9,0.1,459.4,0,394.7V117.3C0.1,52.6,52.6,0.1,117.3,0h277.3C459.4,0.1,511.9,52.6,512,117.3
        v277.3C511.9,459.4,459.4,511.9,394.7,512z M117.3,64C87.9,64,64,87.9,64,117.3v277.3c0,29.5,23.9,53.3,53.3,53.3h277.3
        c29.5,0,53.3-23.9,53.3-53.3V117.3c0-29.5-23.9-53.3-53.3-53.3H117.3z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M206.2,379.5c-13.5,0-26.4-5.4-35.8-14.9l-63.7-63.6c-12.5-12.5-12.5-32.8,0-45.3c0,0,0,0,0,0l0,0
        c12.5-12.5,32.8-12.5,45.2,0l54.3,54.3l153.9-153.9c12.5-12.5,32.8-12.5,45.2,0l0,0c12.5,12.5,12.5,32.8,0,45.3c0,0,0,0,0,0
        L242,364.6C232.6,374.2,219.7,379.5,206.2,379.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Black is the default fill of any shape in svg. I suspect you may have an external style for the tick. If this is not the case can you please edit your question and add the svg code?

Comment: What  you have in your code is a filled path with a tick like hole. Not at all like what you show in the attached images.

Comment: @enxaneta sorry I edit the code

Comment: instead of the <path class="st0" please try `<path fill="#FF2D78"`.

Answer (score 0):

*This did not solve this users issue but still provides helpful information for others looking for answers to similar problems.*

You need to update the svg asset file name if it has changed in your pubspec.yaml file. The file should look something like this:

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/my_svg.svg
```

Then if you are in VS Code, either right click and select get packages, or run `flutter pub get` in the terminal. You should then have your updated svg available. Every time you update or change an image you must run `flutter pub get` because if you don't flutter will continue to use your old image.

Comment: I use `assets: -assets/svg/` and put all this file. and when I do `flutter pub get` it doesn't update svg image.

Comment: If you've done the above steps it should be updated. Is the old svg also still in the directory or did you replace it?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly you had an svg that we will call old.svg. You changed the check mark color and now have an svg that we'll call new.svg. But flutter is continuing to show old.svg even though you have replaced or edited it with new.svg.

Comment: yes your understanding is correct, I stop emulator and restart several times with flutter pub get and flutter clean ...etc

Comment: I remove only svg from directory